# Grid view onclick is not working

Tags: java, android, gridview

I need to make ItemClickListener on grid view.  I am adding buttons dynamically on gridvie. Using Base adapter. I need to onItemClickListener in  my activity not on baseadapter class.

My xml code :

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
/>
```

DirectOrder class:

```
public class DIrectOrder extends Activity {

    DbHelper db;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> category = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    BaseAdapter baseAdapter;
    LinearLayout categroyLayout;
    String strCategory = "";
    GridView grdView;
    static String[] itemName = new String[10];;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.cash_directorder);
        db = new DbHelper(DIrectOrder.this);
        grdView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        categroyLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay_category);
        category = db.retrieve_category_name();
        strCategory = category.get(0).get("name");
        items = db.retrieve_item_details(strCategory);
        for (int i = 0; i < category.size(); i++) {
            Button butCategory = new Button(this);
            butCategory.setText(category.get(i).get("name"));
            butCategory.setId(Integer.parseInt(items.get(i).get("Id")));
            categroyLayout.addView(butCategory);

        }
        Log.i("Item name  ::::", "" + items.get(0).get("Item_Name"));
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            itemName[i] = items.get(i).get("Item_Name");
        }
        grdView.setAdapter(new categoryAdapter(this, itemName));

     // I need on click of the gridview on here // 
        grdView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("Clciking", "Click");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My base adapter class:

```
public class categoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    String[] itemname;

    public categoryAdapter(Context c, String[] itemname) {
        mContext = c;
        this.itemname = itemname;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemname.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Button butCatrgory = new Button(mContext);
        butCatrgory.setId(position);

        butCatrgory.setHeight(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        butCatrgory.setText(itemname[position]);

        return butCatrgory;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines in your MyBaseAdapter class' getview method after butCatrgory.setId(position);

```
butCatrgory.setEnabled(false);
butCatrgory.setClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Button` are by default focusable and that should prevent OnItemClickListener to be called. Add

```
butCatrgory.setFocusable(false);
```

inside your `getView`